# 'dev_addr' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, power-management, nios

I'm using NIOS II - Eclipse
Here is a sample of my code
I'm basically trying to call a function

```
struct DevDesc {

u32* mmio;

}

struct DevDesc dev_desc;

struct MemDesc mem_desc_g;//this structure is defined in another file

struct SysDesc sys_desc_g = {

.dd = &dev_desc,

.md = &mem_desc_g,

};

u32 power_mode_sleep (struct SysDesc *sd)

{

void * dev_addr = sd->dd->mmio;

//code
//code
//code

return 0;

}
```

and a few lines later I try to call it

```
int main()

{

power_mode_sleep((u32*)dev_addr);

}
```

When i try to build it throws up the error 'dev_addr'  undeclared (first use in this function) and it points to the line

```
power_mode_sleep((u32*)dev_addr);
```

I tried to make the code brief, only putting what I thought was necessary. If anyone would like to see more details I would be happy to provide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `void * dev_addr = sd->dd->mmio;` is restricted to the scope of the function `power_mode_sleep (struct SysDesc *sd)` Hence the error.

Also, you are passing `(u32*)dev_addr` as a parameter to `power_mode_sleep`. Whereas, it expects a parameter of type `struct SysDesc *`

Comment: ok, when I tried to declare dev_addr in the main like such


    main()

{

    struct SysDesc * sd;

    void * devaddr = sd->dd->mmio

    power_mode_sleep((u32*)dev_addr;

    }

It got rid of the error, but throws up a warning "passing argument 1 of 'power_mode_sleep' from incompatible pointer type

Comment: yeah, look at your method's parameter. Just send the type struct SysDesc. Not type dev_addr

Comment: Thanks I changed it to 
'power_mode_sleep((struct SysDesc *) &sys_desc_g);'
and it fixed my problem